# Unable to Rewrite URL Linux server ( URL rewriting )

Tags: apache, .htaccess

**main url**

```
 http://wwww.domain-name.com/artwork_detail.php?artid=F3A5ACFA-6B12-D7A6-6637-03AC0F77E3E0
```

**.htaccess**

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule artwork_detail/artid/(.*)/ artwork_detail.php?artid=$1
    RewriteRule artwork_detail/artid/(.*) artwork_detail.php?artid=$1
```

**Expected output**

```
http://wwww.domain-name.com//artwork_detail/artid/F3A5ACFA-6B12-D7A6-6637-03AC0F77E3E0/
```

**Current Output**

```
 http://wwww.domain-name.com/artwork_detail.php?artid=F3A5ACFA-6B12-D7A6-6637-03AC0F77E3E0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules you have rewrites your **expected output** to your **main url**. Each rule only does *one* thing, it rewrites the "first param" to the "second param", where the first is a regex that matches the request. It doesn't do anything about what the rule's output is supposed to do unless you have a rule meant to rewrite it.

Additionally, rewrites are all internal to the server, the browser has **absolutely no idea** a URL is being rewritten. However, external redirects tells the browser "your last request is somewhere else, go **here** in order to get to it". It sounds like you want your main URL to get externally redirected to your expected output, and not internally rewritten (though you'll need them to internally rewrite them *back* to the main URL in order for any of your pages to work).

So use this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+artwork_detail\.php\?artid=([A-Z0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^ /artwork_detail/artid/%1/? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^artwork_detail/artid/([A-Z0-9-]+)/? /artwork_detail.php?artid=$1 [L]
```